# Is it possible to use a gradient over a css background image?

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I am trying to get a div to have a blue background image which is 500px wide. I then am trying to get the gradient to be white at the very left of the div and as it goes right the background image is slowly visible

Comment: have you tried anything ? gradient background is not working in old browsers, will you consider alternatives ?

Comment: Im using this so far, but cant get the gradient the way i want it. background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 90%),  
url('../images/darkBg.jpg') repeat;

Comment: here is a jsfiddle of what im trying to get http://jsfiddle.net/h37M9/

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/h37M9/5/

Comment: @adrift yes but with using hex instead. I see the last 0 in the rgba does something. How can I do that with hex please

Comment: Yes that is for transparency, you won't be able to do it with hex values I'm afraid :(

Comment: oh right, guess ill just have to get used to using RGB. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

This css code will be useful to make it gradient

```
.gradient {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    background: #999; /* for non-css3 browsers */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ccc,  #000); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
}
```

Use the above css in html using class

```
<div class="gradient">
    gradient box
</div>
```

Comment: You missed 2 CSS entries : `linear-gradient` & `-o-linear-gradient` for full cross-browser support. (good to have fall back). Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Answer (score 0):

I actually just posted something similar on another question, but it applies in this case as well. Here it is in action:

http://sassmeister.com/gist/3528cb23d3e831231949

And the CSS to achieve this effect:

```
.hero {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background: url("http://placesheen.com/1200/500") center center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 }
.hero:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
height: 508px;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), white);
}
```

Of course be sure to add the correct vendor-prefixes so that it is cross-browser compatible. And if you wanted to change gradient directions you would change the gradient values.

The html:

```
<div class="hero">
    You could put content here if you want
</div>
```

More on gradients:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp